# Error when using xmonad on Debian Buster after distribution upgrade

Tags: debian, lightdm, xmonad, gdm

Upgrading Debian from stretch to buster, and I've had troubles starting `xmonad`.

### What doesn't work

I previously started from the login manager, but now either with `gdm3` or `lightdm`, I get thrown out directly.

### Workaround

After I login from a raw console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>), I can start xmonad if I create a file `~/.xinitrx` and run `startx`.

### What I want

I would like to be able to select `xmonad` in `gdm3`, then login, as I used to do in stretch.

I'm using a default minimalist config (works from the console), so I don't think that's the problem.

Please tell me what log files might be relevant to sent!

## Logs

`/var/log/syslog` at the attempt of login:

```
Aug 13 09:12:24 vinden systemd[1]: session-c8.scope: Killing process 15753 (lightdm) with signal SIGTERM.
Aug 13 09:12:24 vinden systemd[1]: session-c8.scope: Killing process 15756 (lightdm-gtk-gre) with signal SIGTERM.
Aug 13 09:12:24 vinden systemd[1]: session-c8.scope: Killing process 15769 (uim-helper-serv) with signal SIGTERM.
Aug 13 09:12:24 vinden systemd[1]: Stopping Session c8 of user lightdm.
Aug 13 09:12:24 vinden systemd[1]: session-66.scope: Failed to add inotify watch descriptor for control group /user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-66.scope: No space left on device
Aug 13 09:12:24 vinden systemd[1]: Started Session 66 of user gauthier.
Aug 13 09:12:24 vinden at-spi-bus-launcher[8381]: dbus-daemon[8385]: Activating service name='org.a11y.atspi.Registry' requested by ':1.5' (uid=1000 pid=15983 comm="trayer --edge top --align right --SetDockType true")
Aug 13 09:12:24 vinden at-spi2-registr[15994]: Could not open X display
Aug 13 09:12:24 vinden at-spi-bus-launcher[8381]: dbus-daemon[8385]: Successfully activated service 'org.a11y.atspi.Registry'
Aug 13 09:12:24 vinden at-spi-bus-launcher[8381]: SpiRegistry daemon is running with well-known name - org.a11y.atspi.Registry
Aug 13 09:12:24 vinden at-spi2-registr[15994]: AT-SPI: Cannot open default display
Aug 13 09:12:24 vinden dbus-daemon[7613]: [session uid=1000 pid=7613] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.portal.IBus' requested by ':1.22' (uid=1000 pid=15977 comm="/usr/bin/ibus-daemon --daemonize --xim ")
Aug 13 09:12:24 vinden dbus-daemon[7613]: [session uid=1000 pid=7613] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.portal.IBus'
Aug 13 09:12:25 vinden systemd[1]: session-66.scope: Killing process 15897 (lightdm) with signal SIGTERM.
Aug 13 09:12:25 vinden systemd[1]: session-66.scope: Killing process 15903 (gnome-keyring-d) with signal SIGTERM.
Aug 13 09:12:25 vinden systemd[1]: session-66.scope: Killing process 15906 (xmonad-session) with signal SIGTERM.
Aug 13 09:12:25 vinden systemd[1]: session-66.scope: Killing process 15960 (ssh-agent) with signal SIGTERM.
Aug 13 09:12:25 vinden systemd[1]: session-66.scope: Killing process 15977 (ibus-daemon) with signal SIGTERM.
Aug 13 09:12:25 vinden systemd[1]: session-66.scope: Killing process 15988 (ibus-dconf) with signal SIGTERM.
Aug 13 09:12:25 vinden systemd[1]: session-66.scope: Killing process 16007 (dropbox) with signal SIGTERM.
Aug 13 09:12:25 vinden systemd[1]: session-66.scope: Killing process 16008 (dropbox) with signal SIGTERM.
Aug 13 09:12:25 vinden systemd[1]: Stopping Session 66 of user gauthier.
Aug 13 09:12:25 vinden acpid: client 15746[0:0] has disconnected
Aug 13 09:12:25 vinden acpid: client connected from 16014[0:0]
Aug 13 09:12:25 vinden acpid: 1 client rule loaded
Aug 13 09:12:26 vinden systemd[1]: session-c9.scope: Failed to add inotify watch descriptor for control group /user.slice/user-118.slice/session-c9.scope: No space left on device
Aug 13 09:12:26 vinden systemd[1]: Started Session c9 of user lightdm.
```

Comment: What do you mean by "thrown out"? Back to the login manager?

Comment: @Paradox Yes. I'd be happy to find a log file of that event.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the log you provided is for `lightdm`. What got my attention as well is "user.slice/user-118.slice/session-c9.scope: No space left on device" ; do you have some space left for `/home`?

Comment: @Paradox I agree. `df -h` is fine though, 78% usage on `/home`, and no other filesystem is full.

Comment: I do not get one thing: why your question is about how to do this in `gdm3` since you are using `lightdm`? `xmonad` works with `lightdm` in your case?

Comment: @Paradox: I understand why this is confusing, sorry about that. It wasn't working in either case, so I needed help to fix it for any. Anyway, problem solved and I'll post a solution now (the problem was with another program which ran at login, and segfaulted, crashing the whole process).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, but was unrelated. I'll post how I debugged this problem.

I needed to check `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`, but the file was somehow truncated so that I missed the error.

- login in another tty with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
- save all new input in the log file to a separate file: `tail -f /var/log/Xorg.0.log >> ~/tmp/Xorg.log`
- return to the login manager with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.
- attempt to login, in my case it crashed and returned to the login manager.
- return to your other tty with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, observe what happened in `~/tmp/Xorg.log`.

In my case, if you must know, `xkbcomp` crashed with a segmentation fault because of an error in my keyboard config file, taking with it the whole thing. I suppose that `xkbcomp` is a newer version than the one I previously had (because I upgraded Debian), and is less resilient to config errors than the older version.